# Column gutter issue in Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

So I've set up my webpage so the background image is 12 images divided into columns. I did this because I both need some more images to stack on top of the background image and collapse the exact same way, and I need multiple background images, one for each media query. So my problem is that everything works great until I get to about 775px width, then the gutters reappear and the columns start stacking vertically if I move smaller, despite the fact that I specified a setup for column xs. The gutter's aren't even working right in the codepen, so maybe I'm doing this all wrong all together. I'm new to bootstrap and web development so I probably did something silly!

I've added pics for the original, the fullscreen background, medium sized browser window, and where it breaks. Also, here's the codepen link. http://codepen[dot]io/kathryncrawford/pen/GpeyGP

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just as an aside, I've tried setting the background with css, and the images on top just don't line up when I do. Doesn't matter if I do fixed, cover, whatever, it just doesn't line up :(

Comment: Have you tried using a HTML map tag? Info at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `<map>` element you can then use the `<img>` attribute to achieve what you need. I have used this for a webpage I created. The `<map>` element allowed me to do this perfectly as I was able to manipulate the image using the `shape`, `coords`, and `href` attributes. By using the `shape` and `coords` attributes I was able to select each individual image from the map and allow the full section of each to act as a clickable link. `Href` allowed me to include the page links that take the user to their chosen selection. To obtain the coordinates I took the top left corner and bottom right corner of each house image and included these within the `coords` attribute to specify the dimensions of the image.

For example

```
<map name="test">
  <img src="images/back/background1.png" usemap="#test" height="set your height" width="set your width" ismap="ismap" />
  <area shape="default" coords="8,0, 184, 826" href="insert the link for the page that you want the user to be directed too" alt="" />
</map>
```

This means you can use just one image for your overall background instead of including the same image mutliple times.

Comment: If i use the map element, will my page remain responsive? Can I switch out background images at media queries?

Comment: it will remain responsive aslong as you use % and not pixels. Yes you can still switch out background images at media queries

Comment: Sweeeeet. I'll give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, let me know how you get on. It will also cut down the number of divs you need to use, because instead of using the background image over and over again within divs, the map element only needs to use one image

Comment: Well I'll still need to position the images on top of the background. I may do that with map, or position them absolutely. Whatever works.

Comment: will the images be clickable links?

Comment: No, nothing needs to be clickable. I just need them to stay in the same position relative to the background when the window is resized. They have to be seperate images because they'll be animated.

Comment: Bootstarp should take care of that for you if you use class="col-md" or "col-xs" depending on how many images you want to use